# Cut/delete part of plot

Tags: matlab, layout, plot, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I have the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, the plot has some data on the left (blue) and on the right (red). However, I want them to be closer together. For example by cutting the box area, because there is no data, such that the 'red area' is more shifted to the left (and thus closer to the 'blue area').

How to proceed further?

MWE:

```
x = 0:0.05:1.3
y = x;
plot(x,y,'color','k','Linewidth',1);
hold on;
x1 = [0.1:0.05:x(end)];
y1 = [0:0.05:y(end)-0.1];
plot(x1,y1,'--k','Linewidth',1);
x2 = [0:0.05:x(end)];
y2 = [0.10:0.05:y(end)+0.1];
plot(x2,y2,'--k','Linewidth',1);
xlim([0 x(end)]);
ylim([0 y(end)]);
hold on
for i = 1:9;
   a = plot(P(i).mHlfA1,P(i).sHlfA1, 'bx');
   hold on
   b = plot(P(i).mHlfA1,P(i).sLFA1, 'bo');
   hold on
   c = plot(P(i).mHlfA2,P(i).sHlfA2, 'rd');
   hold on
   d = plot(P(i).mHlfA2,P(i).sLFA2, 'r*');
   hold on;
end
```

Comment: Do you want an x-axis discontinuity or do you want to shift the data?

Comment: Discontinuity. So the point should have the same values on the axis.

Comment: [relevant link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94288-how-do-i-create-breaks-in-the-x-axis-range-of-values-to-plot-data-with-large-gaps-in-the-x-data-more). Can't be done natively, but the workaround is to create two separate axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative tweak (to that suggested in the comments), using the `XtickLable`:

```
x = [1:10 200:2:230];
y = 3.*x-9;
% define the parts of he x-axis:
xgap = 11;
% pasting together the two parts:
new_x = [x(1:xgap-1) x(xgap-1)+(x(xgap:end)-x(xgap))+(x(xgap+2)-x(xgap+1))];
ax = axes;
plot(ax,new_x,y,'o');
% get the ticks to change:
left_x_tick = ax.XTick(ax.XTick<=x(xgap-1));
right_x_tick = ax.XTick(ax.XTick>x(xgap-1));
slash = left_x_tick(end)+floor((right_x_tick(1)-left_x_tick(end))/2);
ax.XTick = [left_x_tick slash right_x_tick];
% get the spacing between ticks
inc = right_x_tick - min(right_x_tick);
% create new tick labels:
new_tick = cellstr(num2str(inc.' + min(x(xgap:end))+(right_x_tick(1)-new_x(xgap))));
% replace the tick labels in the plot
ax.XTickLabel(ax.XTick>new_x(xgap)) = new_tick;
% put a // where there is a gap:
slash_loc = find(ax.XTick==slash,1,'first');
ax.XTickLabel(slash_loc) = {'//'};
ax.FontSize = 14;
```

This is **before**:

[image: no gap in x axis]

and **after**:

[image: gap in x axis]

This is just an idea for workaround, it could be further adjusted to the specific needs.